# Outlook add-in : How can I know when Recurrence null

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

I know  Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged but It's work only recurrence to recurrence or null to recurrence

I wanna catch event when change outlook recurrence to null

How can I know that please help

`Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged`